# Phpmyadmin no me deja hacer registro sin contraseña (usuario: 'root' pass:'' )

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, windows10

estoy Montando un servidor en win10 sin wampp ni similares, paso a paso, el caso es que la instalacion de apache, y su virtual host, mysql y php han salido bien, pero a la hora de phpmyadmin, cuando sale la pantalla de registro, me sale un error que dice que no se permite el registro sin contraseña.

Mirando por foros la unica solución que he visto era en la configuración de phpmyadmin poner la parte de AllowNopassword en True (lo tengo ya en true) también probe a directamente ponerle una contraseña(root) en el mismo archivo de configuración y tampoco funciona en ese caso me sale otro error de acceso denegado para el usuario root(using password: yes).

Es para un trabajo de clase, con esto quiero decir que todavia no soy ningun experto en levantar servidores y me estoy volviendo vastante loco.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que indicas entiendo que cambiaste el archivo /phpmyadmin/config.inc.php activando la siguiente linea:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

Luego reiniciaste el servicio?

Todas las pruebas las hiciste sobre localhost verdad?

Sino pasame versión de MySQL (he visto por ahí que nuevas versiones de MySQL van a prohibir acceso sin pass para root)